# How to get JSON tree structure from neo4j?

Tags: json, neo4j

I have a Person label and have 2 relationships among persons :FATHER and :MOTHER, so I try to get a family tree from neo4j such as

```
{
        'PersonName': 'John',
        'PersonsAncestors': 
            [
                {
                    'MotherName': 'someName',
                    'MotherAncestors: 
                        [
                            {
                                'MotherName': 'someName',
                                'MotherAncestors: [...]
                            },
                            {
                                'FatherName': 'someName',
                                'FatherAncestors: [...]
                            }
                        ]
                },
                {
                    'FatherName' 'someName',
                    'FatherAncestors: 
                        [
                            {
                                'MotherName': 'someName',
                                'MotherAncestors: [...]
                            },
                            {
                                'FatherName': 'someName',
                                'FatherAncestors: [...]
                            }
                        ]
                }
            ]
    }
```

Is it even possible?

Tried something like that

```
MATCH tree =  (mother:Person)<-[:Mother|:Father*0..2]-(rootPerson:Person {uuid: '50d89cbd-15f6-11e6-ac0e-005056b316bf'})RETURN nodes(tree)
```

Maybe I can loop results and create some kind of collection?